# EnableAutomaticMigrations Error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to run the following command in Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
```

But I keep getting the following output:

```
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0
```

My app.config file contains this connection string:

```
<add name="EFDataAccessLayer.My.MySettings.SQLServerConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=CDV-WIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=Test" />
```

And I've also tried this:

```
<add name="EFDataAccessLayer.My.MySettings.SQLServerConnectionString"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; Data Source=CDV-WIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=Test&quot;" />
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you make sure to set the startup project in the PM Console and solution explorer?

Comment: @DrewJordan Yes I did. I seem to have got around this problem but I'm not sure what I did to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you select the right `Default project` in the `Package Manager Console`, it is still looking at the web.config file of the current startup project, where the connection string isn't present.

Set the project containing your `DbContext` class as the startup project to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue in Web API 2 after running this in PM console:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ConnectionString IdentityConnection -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -Force
```

I fixed it by changing it to actually use the `ApplicationDbContext` created in `IdentityModels`.

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
```

The interesting thing is not only does this reference the same exact connection string, but the constructor includes code that someone in another post said was a potential fix (i.e., the `throwIfV1Schema: false` suggestion.